# When i installing my wordpress website in my local server it redirecting the live url when i am loading the url of localhost .

Tags: wordpress, live

Sometime it redirecting to live or it showing not found page 
NOTE : I changed all the live url to localhost in the database and  set up in the way it should be done.
i cant determine the problem

Comment: check any site URL mentioned in wp-config.php and update it as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can try below solutions

1) Delete .htaccess file from your project root folder in localhost and generate again using permalink from wp-admin -> Settings-> Permalink just click save button and it will generate automatically to root folder of the project.

2) Go to wp-admin -> Settings -> Genral Settings change

```
WordPress Address (URL) -> to http://localhost/your project name
Site Address (URL)      -> to http://localhost/your project name
```

3) Make sure that in Wamp or Xamp server the Apache Modules rewrite_module is      on

Comment: This is helpful  thanks , i found that there are some plugins are causing this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Change and Update WordPress URLS in Database When Site is Moved to new Host  and check htacess file

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Comment: I have changed i said that